# UWP inherit from my Usercontrol

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp, contentpresenter

I am trying to create a `ModalPage` class, it run's well but I want to create 4 subclass to specialize my `ModalPage`.
[image: Screenshot]

My `ModalPage` inherit from `UserControl` (XAML + C#). On my sub-classes which inherit from my `ModalPage`, I must parameterize a specific contents and titles.

I suppose, the best way is to do like the `ContentDialog` class, have a c# class whith `ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog` and a XAML page with:

```
<ContentDialog>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

But I can't inherit from my `UserControl`, because it uses XAML. Should I create a custom control (inherit from `Control`) instead of a `UserControl`?

Comment: If only your title and content is changing, then I would suggest to create User control, and expose two dependency property to set the value of title and content from parent page.

Comment: thanks ! but i have a lot of content, if i expose dependency property to set  the value of content in my userControl, the content can be another UserControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I expose dependency property to set the value of content in my userControl, the content can be another UserControl?

Yeah, we can use [`ContentPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) to implement this. Following is a simple sample:

In XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UWP.ModalPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="using:UWP"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Title"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                          Content="{x:Bind ModalTitle}" />
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Content="{x:Bind ModalContent}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class ModalPage : UserControl
{
    public ModalPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModalTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ModalTitle", typeof(object), typeof(ModalPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object ModalTitle
    {
        get { return GetValue(ModalTitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModalTitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModalContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ModalContent", typeof(object), typeof(ModalPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object ModalContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(ModalContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModalContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then we can use this `ModalPage` in pages like:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:ModalPage ModalTitle="TITLE">
        <local:ModalPage.ModalContent>
            <local:MyUserControl />
        </local:ModalPage.ModalContent>
    </local:ModalPage>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. I want to know if it is possible to inherit from My ModalClass ? My solution seems to be hard but I should prefer  define the content and title on the xaml of the subclass.

Comment: It's possible to inherit from your `ModalClass`. However, usually we won't create a user control inherit from another user control. As you can see by default, the class inherit from `UserControl` is `sealed`. And like Kiran Paul said, if you only want to change title and content, exposing two dependency property in your `UserControl` is enough. If you prefer to define the content and title on the xaml of the subclass then you'd better create a custom control instead of user control.

Comment: Thank, now I uses dependency property, this question was only for learn more about c# and xaml =)